# I just add facebookloginbutton in xml but its not work

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

This my error when I run app: 
 Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.
I just want to show button login but its not work with genymotion (I buid apk and run in my device not work too)

[This is my code info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBr89.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Intialise the facebook sdk before setcontentview method

Refer here for more:https://coderzpassion.com/android-using-facebook-login-application-using-latest-facebook-sdk/

Comment: ok its work! Thanks so much! Sorry for my stupid ques :D. I doesn't work with android before